# php array and html

Tags: php, html, arrays

OK i have 2 files one is index.php and the other is file.html now i want to display my array content through that html file like calling it and then displaying here is the code

```
index.php:

$var1 = 'text';

array('var' => $var1);

include ('file.html');


file.html:

<p>html {var} html</p>
```

now its not displaying text i have seen people use {} and call the key and display its value how do i do that? all i want is display my values through the html file not with echo or using php open close codes in between the html codes.

Comment: You could go through some Template Engines for example Smarty. How they are doing and can use Template engines instead. They did it already for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace tags `{name}` to value with `$a = array('name' => 'value');` you can use `str_replace();`

```
$filehtml = file_get_contents('file.html');
$array = array('var' => 'value');

foreach($array as $tag => $value)
{
  $filehtml = str_replace('{'.$tag.'}', $value, $filehtml);
}

echo $filehtml;
```

Or you use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) (or others).

Answer (score 0):

you must use template engines like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), or [PatTemplate](http://pear.php-tools.net/index.php?package=patTemplate). or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doens't do anything with {var} statement. You should work with it manually... or read about template engines http://www.smarty.net/ for e.g.

Answer (score 0):

What you saw I assume were templates of some template engine or other. When using templates, the (HTML) template files are parsed on runtime and the placeholders ({var}) are replaced with their values. If you google around for PHP template engine a bit I'm sure you'll get the idea of it and/or find an existing solution to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the way of templating but here's a rough snippet, so you get the idea.

```
$var1 = 'text';
$tags = array('var' => $var1);

$tpl = file_get_contents('file.html');

foreach($tags as $label => $data) {
    $tpl = str_replace('{' . $label . '}', $data, $tpl);
}

echo $tpl;
```

Comment: Poor method with a lot of variables

Comment: Your code is wrong cause depenting on your loop only 1 tag can be changed.

Comment: @Shakti Singh No one said this is the ultimate templating system but much better than original post IMO.

Comment: Poor copy. Here is error : `$final = str_replace('{' . $label . '}', $data, $tpl);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), just be mindful of collisions!

index.php

```
$var1 = 'text';

$variabbles = array('var' => $var1);
extract ($variables);
include ('file.html');
```

file.html:

```
<p>html <?php echo $var; ?> html</p>
```

Comment: HTML file can not parse PHP variables

Comment: @Shakti - this will work: if you use `include()`, it will be treated as PHP code, even if the file name is .html. That said, I'm not sure that I'd agree with the idea of using `extract()` to achieve this; there are several better ways to do it.

Comment: The code above works. Downvoting answers without a real reason is just plain inconsiderate.

Comment: @Spudley: I agree that extract() isn't the best approach, but it is the closest to what the OP wants.

Comment: If I had to do it like this, I would have enclosed the `include()` inside a function, with its own parameters. This would allow you to specify whatever variables you want without worrying about collisions or making unnecessary globals.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make it easier to work with HTML without having to have PHP code embedded in it. This would be done using a templating language.

There's a number of templating languages available for PHP; the most well-known one is [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

However, I would caution you that if you have any kind of complexity in your pages, you will need some sort of program code. Smarty and others allow you to do loops and conditions, but when used like this, it can very quickly become a programming language in its own right. Plus they add quite a bit of processing overhead, which is really unnecessary.

The bottom line is that for most uses, it's easier just to stick with standard PHP tags for printing your variables into your HTML code.

See also a previous answer I gave to a similar question: [Dirt-simple PHP templates... can this work without `eval`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930053/dirt-simple-php-templates-can-this-work-without-eval/3958625#3958625)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a template engine for this task, I could suggest the following code to add to your index.php:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'text';

$templateVars = array('var' => $var1);

$content = file_get_contents('file.html');

foreach($templateVars as $tplVar => $tplVarContent) {
    $content = preg_replace('/\{' . $tplVar . '\}/', $tplVarContent, $content);
}

echo $content;
```

**Why using `preg_replace()`?**

It's known that `preg_replace()` does a better job at replacing in a bigger text content rather than `str_replace()` which starts to be slower and slower after each replacement (you can find a benchmark on Google, I can't seem to find it right now)

**Later edit:**

I found am improvement on this one.

```
<?php
$var1 = 'test';

$templateVars = array('var' => $var1);

$content = file_get_contents('tpl.tpl');

$content = preg_replace('/\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}/e', "\$templateVars['\\1']", $content);

echo $content;
```

I have also done a little test against the `str_replace()` solution. `str_replace()` is *faster* only when there are a couple of variables (2-3). With 6 variables `preg_replace()` is **2 times faster**.

Here are my results:

```
preg_replace() 10000 times: 0.038811922073364seconds
str_replace() 10000 times: 0.085460901260376seconds
```

This is the code I ran to test the speed:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'text';

$templateVars = array('var' => $var1, 'var1' => 'blabla', 'var3' => 'variable3', 'var22' => $var1, 'var133' => 'blabla', 'var3444' => 'variable3');

$content = file_get_contents('tpl.tpl');


$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) 
{
    $content = preg_replace('/\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}/e', "\$templateVars['\\1']", $content);
}

$end = microtime(true);

echo 'preg_replace() '. $i . ' times: ' . ($end - $start) . 'seconds<br>';


$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) 
{
    foreach($templateVars as $tplVar => $tplVarContent) {
        $content = str_replace('{' . $tplVar . '}', $tplVarContent, $content);
    }
}
$end = microtime(true);

echo 'str_replace() '. $i . ' times: ' . ($end - $start) . 'seconds<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffering to solve your problem but be careful on quotes if you only use php to output it.

Answer (score -2):

PHP doesn't care what file types you include - it will execute them as if they were php files. So.....

```
ndex.php:

$var1 = 'text';

$myArr = array('var' => $var1);

include ('file.html');


file.html:

<p>html <?php print_r($myArr);?> html</p>
```

Comment: minus scores???? lol - just answered the OP - if templating was asked for then I'd have expanded - you guys are harsh ;)

Comment: <p>html Array
(
    [var] => text
)
 html</p> is the output. IF he just wanted $var1 in there then just echo $var1 or $myArr['var'] - nothing wrong with the actual answer surely????

Comment: OP asks for a simple templating system and what you've provided is definitely doesn't do the trick.