# In PHP file, get {$variable} to do the equivalent of <?php echo $variable; ?>

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dirt-simple PHP templates… can this work without `eval`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930053/dirt-simple-php-templates-can-this-work-without-eval)

Let's say I have a text file called `template.tpl`.  The contents of `template.tpl` is:

```
<html>
<body>This is a variable: {$variable}</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way for PHP to render template.tpl as a PHP file and then understand that `{$variable}` should be processed as `<?php echo $variable; ?>`?

Comment: Well, with string processing, there is a way, so the answer is yes. However I wonder with such a trivial answer, why you ask the question. Also I can imagine this has been asked before, so I wonder why you haven't found so far a more detailed answer.

Comment: The question I linked above is basically asking the same question (albeit in a much more long-winded way). The [answer I gave then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930053/dirt-simple-php-templates-can-this-work-without-eval/3958625#3958625) is the same as the one I'd give now. In short: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much trivial with output buffering.

```
$variable = 'I am a variable';
$output = '';
ob_start();
require 'template.tpl';
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* do this sort of thing, use the [Smarty templating language](http://www.smarty.net/). That's what it does, and it's popular enough that it must be doing something right.

However, I would strongly suggest not doing this. See my related answer here: [Dirt-simple PHP templates... can this work without `eval`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930053/dirt-simple-php-templates-can-this-work-without-eval/3958625#3958625)